# Report showing the index column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, procedure

I have a question to generate a report, need it to take data from a SQL table and place the name of the table takes her ID, below the data that the query generates

COD_CLIENTE NOME ENDERECO CPF

```
  2 Fulano               Av. Rio Branco       2837462890           
  3 Ciclano              Rua Zero             4625427282           
  4 Beltrano             Rua Doze             2634623637
```

I created this procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE COLUNAS_TESTE AS 
Cursor linha is
Select cod_cliente, nome, endereco, cpf from clientes where rownum < 4;

rLin linha%rowtype;

BEGIN
Open linha;
Loop

Fetch linha into rLin;

Exit when linha%notFound;

    dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 2'||' Valor: '||rLin.Nome);
    dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 3'||' Valor: '||rLin.Endereco);
    dbms_output.put_line('Linha: '||rLin.cod_cliente||' Coluna: 4'||' Valor: '||rLin.CPF);
End loop;
Close linha;
END;
```

Generating this result

```
Linha: 2 Coluna: 2 Valor: Fulano
Linha: 2 Coluna: 3 Valor: Av. Rio Branco
Linha: 2 Coluna: 4 Valor: 2837462890
Linha: 3 Coluna: 2 Valor: Ciclano
Linha: 3 Coluna: 3 Valor: Rua Zero
Linha: 3 Coluna: 4 Valor: 4625427282
Linha: 4 Coluna: 2 Valor: Beltrano
Linha: 4 Coluna: 3 Valor: Rua Doze
Linha: 4 Coluna: 4 Valor: 2634623637
```

Line and value OK, he gets the code, but I need two reports, one in place of the column he put the field name, and another that put the column index, there did gambiarra to put the "fixed", but need it dynamically, I hope you managed to explain.

Even managed to make a select to search this data, but could not relate it with my column, if someone can help and I have been able to explain the problem.

```
 select COLUNAS.COLUMN_ID AS COLUNAS_ID ,COLUNAS.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUNAS_NOME
 from USER_TAB_COLUMNS COLUNAS
 where COLUNAS.TABLE_NAME = 'CLIENTES';
```

Comment: Sorry, but do not understand the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to describe better.

2 procedure will be created, one for each report.

The customer wants it to appear that way that on the screen, as a result generates, row / column / value. Currently the column is being passed fixed, I need you in one procedure this value dynamically receive the column index, which is in the last select the question, and the other procedure the column receives the name of the column is in the select and not its value.

I hope you have been able to explain properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the same problem, when I was writting checker column by column with undifined column list.

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/535357/7) example, maybe it could help

Comment: Also you could use column name or column comment for better output understanding

Comment: Thanks, I'll analyze this sql, but already gave me a beautiful way of direction to follow